# Clang tooling. Type name without keyword

Tags: clang, keyword, libtooling

I'm working on some clang tool, and I need to generate source code with types, that aren't specified explicitly.
The strings with types I get from `clang::QualType`  is something like: `class std::initializer_list<int>`. The issue is to get type without keyword.

I've tried to `dyn_cast<>` types (`clang::Type`) to all heirs of `TypeWithKeyword` but the result is always null.

Of course I can delete all occurrence of "class", "struct", etc. from the string with type name, but I would like to solve this in "clang way".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was simple.
Instead of using `QualType::getAsString()`, just needed `QualType::getAsString (const PrintingPolicy &Policy)`.
So the code:

```
PrintingPolicy pp(f_context->getLangOpts());
string typeName = qualType.getAsString(pp);
```

Works well without changing fields of `PrintingPolicy`.